# Animating UIImageView with CIFilter output causes high memory allocation and crash in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, core-image, cifilter

I have added Core Image filter using below code,

```
CIImage *beginImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.originalImage.CGImage];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"
                                      keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage,
                            @"inputIntensity", @0.8, nil];

CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

UIImage *imageWithFilter = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];

self.showImgView.image = imageWithFilter;
```

But a when I try to animate this `self.showImgView`, It increases memory allocation instantly and  goes upto 400MB - 600MB and then crashes.

If anyone has got any suggestions, Please share.

Thank you for your support in advance.

Comment: How is this code block called?

Comment: This code block is inside a function, So i call this function using button click.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue is that you have to be very careful allocating images in an iOS app because images take up a huge amount of memory. And if you allocate lots and lots of images then that takes up even more memory. In your specific case you will need to walk through the code and determine why refs to the UIImage or CIImage are being held. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235528/763355) for a some general memory usage rule of thumb info the iOS apps.